# Can't return more than one SQL row data using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a database where I store multiple lines with its points, color, width, etc. I know that the points are being stored because I checked the SQL table and it is in there. However, when I try to reload these points it will only load the very last line that I stored. I cannot figure out why this is.

```
  private void opendbtestToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("blahblabhblah; "))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Line", conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Shape Line = new Line();            // New line
                            Line.readSQL();
                            shapeList.Add(Line);
                            Invalidate();

                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)

        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        }
```

the readSQL function

```
public override void readSQL()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("blahblahblah; "))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Line", conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader != null)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                // string s = (reader["ID"].ToString());
                                int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["x1"]);
                                int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["x2"]);
                                int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["y1"]);
                                int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["y2"]);
                                Pt1 = new Point(x1, y1);
                                Pt2 = new Point(x2, y2);
                                PenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Width"]);
                                PenColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Color"]));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           // MessageBox.Show(PenColor.ToString());
           // MessageBox.Show(PenWidth.ToString());
        }
    }
```

how I write to the database

```
public override void writeSQL()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("blahblahblah "))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Line (x1,x2,y1,y2, Width, Color) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5, @val6)";
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", Pt1.X);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", Pt2.X);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", Pt1.Y);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", Pt2.Y);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", PenWidth);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", PenColor.ToArgb());
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Insertion complete");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "fuuuu");

                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Create an object and add it to a collection

Comment: Where the Pt1, Pt2 assigned? Why there are two SqlConnection/Command/Reader?

Comment: I've updated the original post to make it a little more clear. There are two sqlconnections/command/reader because they are in different files.

Comment: @Vince, Why are you call readsql function in the main thread, is it necessary to read sql again?

Comment: Dear @vince, Shape Line = new Line();   !!!! What is this??? Shape Line = new Shape();   !! Which one?

Comment: The reasoning is because we were given a skeleton code where it contains the shapelist and we are not allowed to modify it. It is Shape Line = new Line(); because of preexisting code that uses a switch case.   public static Shape CreateShape(ShapeType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case ShapeType.Line:
                    return new Line();

Comment: @Vince  '`Line.readSQL();` - completely useless unless you pass the `reader` object like this: '`Line.readSQL(reader);`

Comment: I get a no overload for method readSQL error if I put the reader in. I also removed it from my code and executed without it, it won't even place a line down so it isn't useless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this. Execute your query and load all your data into `datatable`. After that you can loop through each record

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Line";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());  
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
    {
       //manipulate your data
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

send sqlDataReader to another function and manipulate data in that function, something like that:

```
    public bool InitializeVariables(SqlDataReader sdr, bool isSingle = true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                if (isSingle)
                    sdr.Read();

                //initialize and manipulate data here.

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, a `Line` is a singular object. You are calling `ReadSQL` as a non-static method on a Line object, and expecting it to return more than one line, but this doesn't really make sense - your method is setting two properties on the current object, so by definition, only the last item in your collection will be "returned".

Your code in `ReadSQL` makes more sense if it was selecting for a specific Id, e.g.

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Line Where id = @id", conn))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = id });
  //....
}
```

---

If you want to return a collection of lines, you need to have a method (either as static on the Line object, or elsewhere) that returns a *collection* of line objects.

```
public static IEnumerable<Line> GetLines(int id)
{
    var returnData = new List<Line>();
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("blahblahblah; "))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Line", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // string s = (reader["ID"].ToString());
                    int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["x1"]);
                    int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["x2"]);
                    int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["y1"]);
                    int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["y2"]);

                    returnData.Add(new Line()
                    {
                        Pt1 = new Point(x1, y1),
                        Pt2 = new Point(x2, y2),
                        PenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Width"]),
                        PenColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Color"]))
                    });
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }


    return returnData;
}
```